# How to access antd table current data state?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have a table based on antd table component with custom filters like [components-table-demo-filter-search](https://4x.ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-filter-search)

By default, I can only access to `dataSource` property which I provide but I can't find a way to get access to dataSource after filtering. How can I get access to filtered data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the filtered data source via the `extra` parameter of the `onChange` callback of the `Table` component.

The signature of `onChange`:

```js
function(pagination, filters, sorter, extra: { currentDataSource: [], action: paginate | sort | filter })
```

When the custom `filterSearch` function executes, the `onChange` callback will be executed, and you will get the filtered data source by accessing `extra.currentDataSource`.

Comment: Is there a way to access the state without `onChange` event? I need the initial sorted state.

Comment: @jligeza Sorry, don't understand. Please ask a new question to clarify it